# Proxy class blocks (froze) java application

Tags: java, proxy

I want to check does proxy really works or not for enter any url. I would use

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", ip);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port);
```

but it applies proxy all applications (Threats). 
I want use proxy in specific part of my app. My code is here.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(ip, Integer.parseInt(port)));

URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://google.com");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(200);
    connection.connect();
    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response code of the object is "+code);
    if (code==200)
    {
        System.out.println("OK");
        isResponded=true;
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**All code works and when it reach**

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(ip, Integer.parseInt(port)));
```

**It get frozen or blocked**

Comment: The constructor for `Proxy` basically doesn't do anything: are you 100% sure it blocks there?

Comment: Do you pass the ip as an IPv4 address, an IPv6 address, or as a hostname? If you pass it as a hostname, it may block at `InetSocketAddress` when it tries to resolve tit to an ip address

Comment: I pass ipv4 as an string. @giorgiga I check it when it react there it just wait a lot. does not throw any exception or not finish application.

Comment: Get a thread dump of your application while it's frozen (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstack.html)

Comment: jstack -F mypid says some threads are blocked